# Determining the worst case running time (prime numbers)

Tags: java, complexity-theory, primes

I need help.
I have a method which determines if a int is a prime:

```
public boolean isPrime(int n) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 3; i < n; i += 2) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Could anyone tell me how to determine the worst case time running of this program?
Then let B equal the number of bits in the binary representation of N ... what would be the worst case time running in terms of B?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Well... what do YOU think the worst case run time of this program is? And why?

Answer (score 0):

The running-time of this function is O(n) in every case though in fact the worst case will only come up if n is really a prime number.

Also, if you want to detect all primes in a range from for examle 1 until n, your runtime will be O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

The asymptotic time complexity of your prime number calculator is `O(n)`. There is no reason to incorporate "B" into the calculation of time complexity in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Well at firs glans it seams it will take O(n) but there is an issue here if n=Integer.MaxValue which is equals to 2147483647 at some point you will reach 2147483645 then when adding 2 i will become 2147483647 and in next addition it will become -2147483647 so you have sciped to negative numbers so that may take a while .

Answer (score 0):

Your function incorrectly states that 2 is not a prime number. The third line that currently reads `return false` should read `return (n == 2)` or whatever the proper syntax for that is in Java.

Running time for the algorithm is O(n), which will occur whenever n is prime. You could improve the run time to O(sqrt n) by changing the test in the `for` loop to `i * i <= n`.

Answer (score 0):

The snarky response is to say that it finishes in O(1), because n is bounded above by a 2^31-1 in Java. Hence, I can find a single constant K such that the time is guaranteed to finish in less than that time K.

However, this response does not address what is intended by your question, which is, how the time differs as a function of n within a "reasonable" range for n. As others have pointed out already, your running time will be O(n).

In terms of B, there's a potential bit of confusion, because the integers are *always* represented with a 32-bit signed integer. However, if we ask how many bits are required at maximum for a given value of N, we can note that 2^B < N <= 2^(B+1), so if your calculation requires O(n), it would necessarily require O(2^B) operations.

Also, as others have pointed out, there's an error condition for the value 2 - easily fixable. In addition, this calculation could be easily improved using Sieve methods. While you did not really ask about optimization, I provide the service free of charge. :) See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes for an interesting approach to addressing this problem. And believe it or not, this is really just the *beginning* of optimizing this. There are many more things you can do from there.